# Django - Ajax hidden Model Form

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-forms

I have these 2 models:

```
class Exercise(models.Model):
  text = models.TextField()

class Score(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise)
  score = models.IntegerField()
  class Meta:
    unique_together = (('user', 'exercise',),)
```

A template displays an **exercise** that a **user** can complete.
The **user** gets a **score** at the end.

I'd like to send the score to the database with ajax.

I prepared a view to get the scores

```
def scoresexo(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    ret = {'type': 'info'}
    score, created = Score.objects.get_or_create(
      user = request.user
    , exercise_id = request.POST['exo']
    )
    score.score = request.POST['score']
    try:
      score.save()
    except:
      ret['type'] = 'error'
      ret['msg'] = 'error saving'
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ret), mimetype='application/json')
```

Should I use a hidden [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) or a manual Form/View ?

And what would it be like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need form here? Send get / post request with score and exercise to some view and save the results there.

And don't forget that anyone can make request with any data, so you need to think about some validation.

Comment: That is what I was starting to do but I'm not sure about the reusability and the maintenability of this technique. Is it a good practice ?

Comment: And what's the alternative? You definetely don't need form here (rendering fields, errors, help_text, no need here). So you just need to send data to view. I just recommend to to use something for ajax, my choice is [dajax](http://www.dajaxproject.com/).